# Wordpress static front page with blogposts

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I've created my first wp-theme and right now my first page is dynamic and only shows posts. I want to change that so that I can show a static text first and below I want to be able to show one post from my blog. I Have the perfect example, go to www.mediaanalys.se they have a static text and below they have blogposts. How can I do that?

Comment: can I upload the whole site as a static html file(but change it to .php) and then add dynamic parts? like after my static div add a dynamic statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not a static text. I would suggest it's as **description** of custom-taxonomy/category.
If you click on Sökmotoroptimering (or any other taxonomy in those four-boxes) you will see that text again.

About the slider. It think it's a plugin wich might have own `settings-panel` in the dashboard. (Just google for "free wordpress slider")

P.S. If you want to code something like that by yourself, look into wp codex 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description

You can try to get all categories first and then iterate through and dispaly category-name & its description...